# How can I use date component in a React form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I created a form and it has a date-picker field.  I want to use the [date-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) component but unable to figure out how to get it work.  I'm using the cdn instead of npm and not sure if I'm missing something
critical.

```
class Request extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      location:'',
      date: ''
    }
    this.handleLocation = this.handleLocation.bind(this)
  }
  handleDateSelect(e){
     this.setState({
      date: e.target.value
    })   
  }
  handleLocation(e){
    this.setState({
      location: e.target.value
    })
  }
  handleDateChange(e){
    this.setState({
      date: e.target.value
    })
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
          Today's Date:  <DatePicker selected={this.state.date} onSelect={this.handleDateSelect} onChange={this.handleDateChange} /><br />
          Location: <input type="text" name="location" onChange={this.handleLocation} value={this.state.location} />
        {this.state.location}
      </div>
    )    
  }
}
```

The error that I get is **Uncaught ReferenceError: useState is not defined**
Here's a [pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/OJNeLwY) for more context

Comment: In your sandbox you have `const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());` about which you are getting the error. you are using old way of defining state and you used `useState` and didn't import from React?

Comment: Can I use a cdn to get ```useState```?

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported useState?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

Comment: For reference, your Request class uses the useState hook.
So I think the error is unrelated to DatePIcker, and you just forgot to import the hook  in the file that holds the Request class.

Comment: what about if I just added ```startDate``` and ```setStartDate``` to state? would that work?

Comment: Yes, the useState hook is only for functional components, not Class components. However setStartDate is the function you defined to update that piece of state (startdate). So no need to add that to add that to state as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused.  I'm somewhat new to react. Is my codepen setup wrong?  If I create a ```setStartDate``` function, how do I call it? https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/OJNeLwY?editors=0011

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-benz-rho9y?file=/src/App.js

Here is a working example of datePicker based on your code.
I hope it helps

Comment: Do you know why it's not working in the codepen?  https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/OJNeLwY?editors=0011

Comment: I gave you a working example, that should be more than enough.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I tried your code in my codepen and it didn't work.

Comment: This is no longer a react question, this is a codepen question.